# Net/LDAP gem and basic auth in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm trying to understand the best approach to adding LDAP authentication in a very basic way.

I want to ensure that when coming to the index, a user gets redirected to the login page, then they can use their LDAP Active Directory credentials and when the authentication is valid the rest of the site becomes available.

I was thinking using something like `:before_filter` on each controller to ensure the user is authenticated.

I do not want to store their credentials in the DB since they are already in the Active Directory, I would like to start a session so the user isn't having to login between each page. I've look at using Devise and the LDAP extension and had a basic application with this, but it seems like a lot of overkill. I'm not trying to manage, add users or modifying LDAP attributes, or resetting passwords, etc. I only want some basic authentication before they can access the site and some basic session management to make the experience enjoyable.

I'm looking for any help, ideas, or code examples on how to implement something like this, or maybe just a explanation on how I could achieve something like this.

Here is some code:

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new :host => 'the_server', :auth { :method => :simple, :username => 'user', :password => 'pswd'}
if ldap.bind
 # user is good
else
# user is not ok
end
```

Comment: Have you considered SAML(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) based single sign on option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Gem [devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable).I guess it better suits your requirement.Instead of using your own authentication system, you could use LDAP(Active directory) as an authentication provider.

> If you are building applications for use within your organization
>   which require authentication and you want to use LDAP, this plugin is
>   for you.
>
> Devise LDAP Authenticatable works in replacement of Database
>   Authenticatable. This devise plugin has not been tested with
>   DatabaseAuthenticatable enabled at the same time. This is meant as a
>   drop in replacement for DatabaseAuthenticatable allowing for a semi
>   single sign on approach.

[SAML based single sign on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) is also popularly renowned way of transmitting authentication and authorization information as an `XML`. Service Provider(You) can leverage Identity Provider(Active directory- perhaps **ADFS**) for authentication purposes. [Ruby-SAML by onelogin](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml) is well known gem for SAML implementation.